# jQuery responsive image maps: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, imagemap

I am using [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) to make an image's image map responsive on [this project](http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/).

However, I receive 2 Javascript console errors in Chrome:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rwdImageMaps is not a function
```

I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/wp-content/themes/temper/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    });
</script>
```

just before the closing `</body>` tag, as instructed, however, the console errors remain.

How do I resolve the console errors? Thanks.

Comment: Wait, I didn't download the .js library correctly.

Comment: @emrah: I removed the e parameter, but the error `TypeError: $(...).rwdImageMaps is not a function` remains.

Comment: It is not about errors. it is something you won't use. Anyway everything looks ok. i am deep diving. I hope you don't have a typo.

Comment: Can you try with old jquery. version 1.x. Or make a codepen demo.

Comment: Yep, you have 2 jquery

Comment: Did you try removing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have attached Jquery twice. Remove the one at the header. And move the other above jq ui.